# ¿Por que no puedo importar de un libreria recien descargada?

Tags: python

he instalado pyautoGUI escribiendo en la terminal:
pip install pyautogui
Y tambien he instalado mouse con:
$ pip3 install mousePero al escribir import mouse o import pyautogui no ocurre nada, no lo lee, da error.

Comment: "No ocurre nada" y "da error" son dos cosas bien diferentes... ¿qué error te da?

Comment: No module named 'mouse'

Comment: La causa más probable por la que python no encuentra un módulo que hayas instalado con pip es que tengas dos versiones (al menos) de python en el sistema. En ese caso puede suceder que el pip que estás usando sea el que viene con un python, y en cambio el comando `python` que usas luego sea el otro (que no puede ver lo que está instalado en el primero). Yo siempre aconsejo instalar con `python -m pip install modulo`, para asegurar que el python que ejecutas es el mismo que ha instalado las cosas.

Comment: No me ha funcionado escribiendo eso(he puesto mouse donde modulo)

Comment: Hay otras librerias que si se descargan

Comment: Como "no te ha funcionado"? Algún error en la instalación? O sigue ocurriéndote lo mismo, que no te lo encuentra luego? Usas el mismo python para ejecutar después el `import`, o quizás lo intentas ejecutar desde algún IDE (que podría estar usando otra versión de python)

Comment: Siempre ejecuto desde Visual Studio Code. Es el mismo error de siempre: No module named module. Eso significa que sigue ocurriendome lo smismo. Si es el mismo Python, dependiendo de la libreria que importe, es importado de verdad o no. Por ejemplo pygame fue un exito y puedo importarlo. Es decir la descarga fue util.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente lo que yo hice y me funcionó fué esto:

♦ Desinstalar todos los pythons que tenia debido a que tenia un python que era la version 3.9.7 y no queria importarme las librearias que descargaba.

♦ Instalar el python 3.9 de microsoft store debido a que con este si pude resolver el problema de las librerias y todo funciona a la normalidad.

♦ Una vez instalado escribe en la terminal de windows ejecutada como administrador:

python -m pip install (nombre_de-modulo)

♦ Ya con esto debes esperar un tiempo a que tu programa reaccione que se descargó la libreria, puedes o cerrar el programa de python y esperar un tiempo y abrirlo o cambiarle el nombre al archivo de python que aveces funciona pero no siempre.

Saludos: Kevin

Comment: Además si quieres desinatalar un modilo o libreria que hayas descargado haces el mismo codigo que esta en mi respuesta, pero ya no install sino uninstall

Comment: He desinstalado despues de instalar la de microsoft. (Al abrirlo se abre la que instale anterior mente(3.9.7). Eso ha sido un error ya que ahora no puedo instalar la de microsoft de nuevo. ¿Sabes de algun otro sitio donde pueda instalar una version  que me permita importara parte de miscrosoft store?

Comment: La verdad es mejor descargarlo desde la pagina oficial de python, luego para instalar una libreria te vas al cmd como administrador y digitas esto:

pip install -U (nombre).py

Pero para que te funcione debes añadir python al path, apenas estas instalando la app te sale un cuadro a la izquierda inferior que te dice añadir al path y listo, a mi me funciono esto, no uses lo de microsoft.

Comment: Además la version 3.9.7 no es un error debido a que microsoft trabaja con la ultima version de pytho pero mejor desinstala todo y usa la version de pytho oficial en esta página:
https://www.python.org/downloads/